# How to use dollar sign '$' in raw (multiline) Kotlin strings?

Tags: string, kotlin, escaping

Is there a concise way to escape `$` character in a raw Kotlin string?

In a simple string we use `"\$"`.
In a raw string there is obviuous but superabundant way `"""${"$"}"""` that does not work good when the string contains lot of `$`, i.e. in MongoDB query or some kind of third-party library template.

Comment: I don't know if this is abusing language features, but you can declare a constant called `$`. and use `$\`$\``.

Comment: Please refer to this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2425

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for mongo operators you can define constants to avoid this problem, smth like that

```
object MongoOperators {
    const val eq = "\$eq"
    const val ne = "\$ne"
    const val and = "\$and"
}

val findFilter = """
        {
            $and: [
               "foo": { $eq : 1},
               "bar": { $ne : 2}
            ]
        }
    """.trimIndent()
```

Comment: fresh and brilliant!